# How does PHP/MySQL know to fetch the next row when using mysqli_fetch_array in a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, row

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $q = 'SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category'; 
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    while (list($id,$category) = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo '<li><a href="category.php?id=' . $id . '" title="' . $category . '">' . $category . '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

It looks as though the variable names $id and $category are assigned to a single row fetched from the database through each iteration of the loop. Every time the loop starts over, the next row is chosen. **My question is: how does it *know* to pick the next row in the table?**

It's not like the rows are indexed, such that a 'for' loop can step through all the rows of the table. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: because it implements [traversable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php). Just look up the [mysqli_result class definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) on the PHP site as it will state so. You can actually do this with your own classes as well simply by (correctly) implementing [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) which will allow objects of that class to be traversable in the very same way mysqli_result is. Also if you look on the [page for iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) under examples you'll find a basic mockup of how this is managen inside a class such as mysqli_result.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$r` is an object, which contains information about the latest read row. This is working with [streams too](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php). Think of it as it would have an internal counter which gets incremented each time you call `_fetch_array()`, `_fetch_object()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

After each call to mysqli_fetch_array the internal pointer of the resultset that is represented by `$r` in your example is increased, so the next call return the next element.

Once there are no more elements the returned result is NULL. `While` control structure takes care to stop the process once NULL is returned.

The resultset is based on output of MySQL query it is not necessary to represent a single table.